# Swift How can I load tableViewController and place nth cell on first position but with the ability to scroll up?

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

Let's say I have array of 10 elements and I want the 5th to be at first position in tableView when it loads up but I would like to scroll up to see the first 4 cells.

Comment: Use `tableView. scrollToRow(at:at:animated:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 5, section: 0)
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
}
```

Make sure that the `row` and `section` is correct.